# Multiple level nesting in JSON schema validation with sub-folders

Tags: r, json, jsonschema

I am trying to validate a json file with nested references where the children references are in a sub-folder of the parent one.
The files are organised as following:

```
root/schemas/user
root/schemas/sub-schemas/address
root/schemas/sub-schemas/city
```

and they are referenced `user -> sub-schemas/address -> sub-schemas/city`

I am doing this in R with the package {jsonvalidate} but I guess my question is more about the way references work in the json-schema, rather than R specific. Here's the reproducible code in R which gives the error:

```r
library(jsonvalidate)
library(testthat)

json_to_validate = '
{
  "address":{
    "city":"Firenze"
  }
}
'

root = file.path(tempdir(), "jsonvalidate")
dir = "schemas"
subdir = "sub-schemas"

dir.create(file.path(root, dir, subdir), recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)

user_file = "user"
user_schema_path = file.path(root, dir, user_file)

address_file = "address"
address_rel_path = file.path(subdir, address_file)

city_file = "city"
city_rel_path = file.path(subdir, city_file)

user_schema_ref = sprintf('
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "file://%s",
  "type":"object",
  "required":["address"],
  "properties":{
    "address":{
      "$ref": "%s"
    }
  }
}
', user_schema_path, address_rel_path)


address_schema = sprintf('
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "city":{
      "$ref": "%s"
    }
  }
}
', city_rel_path)


city_schema = sprintf('
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type":"string",
  "enum":["Firenze"]
}
')

write(user_schema_ref, user_schema_path)
write(address_schema, file.path(root, dir, address_rel_path))
write(city_schema, file.path(root, dir, city_rel_path))

list.files(root, recursive = TRUE)
#> [1] "schemas/sub-schemas/address" "schemas/sub-schemas/city"   
#> [3] "schemas/user"

cat(user_schema_ref)
#> 
#> {
#>   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
#>   "$id": "file:///var/folders/yq/82fd9hrj1zs7kx2hqbqlg9280000gp/T//Rtmpguupsl/jsonvalidate/schemas/user",
#>   "type":"object",
#>   "required":["address"],
#>   "properties":{
#>     "address":{
#>       "$ref": "sub-schemas/address"
#>     }
#>   }
#> }
cat(address_schema)
#> 
#> {
#>   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
#>   "type":"object",
#>   "properties":{
#>     "city":{
#>       "$ref": "sub-schemas/city"
#>     }
#>   }
#> }
cat(city_schema)
#> 
#> {
#>   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
#>   "type":"string",
#>   "enum":["Firenze"]
#> }

json_validate(entry1, user_schema_path, engine = "ajv",
              verbose = TRUE, greedy = TRUE, 
              error = FALSE)
#> Error in context_eval(join(src), private$context, serialize, await): Error: can't resolve reference sub-schemas/city from id sub-schemas/address
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I managed to make it work if I put the files all in the same folder:

```
root/schemas/user
root/schemas/address
root/schemas/city
```

And I reference as following:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "file:///var/folders/yq/82fd9hrj1zs7kx2hqbqlg9280000gp/T//Rtmpguupsl/jsonvalidate/schemas/user",
  "type":"object",
  "required":["address"],
  "properties":{
    "address":{
      "$ref": "address"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "city":{
      "$ref": "city"
    }
  }
}
```

But, as soon as I move the sub-schemas in a sub-folder I can't make it work.

Comment: This might be helpful to understand how references work in JSON Schema., https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html. It's hard to tell from what you've provided, but I suspect there's a problems with the URIs you're using.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers thanks for your comment. I know the page, I tried to setup the example based on that documentation but I didn't manage to make it work. If you can, would you mind suggesting how to make my example easier to understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was specific to the R package `jsonvalidate` and the issue has been resolved in PR [#62](https://github.com/ropensci/jsonvalidate/pull/62). The reference `child2` in the example below is resolved against `child1` so it should not contain the sub folder.

```r
library(jsonvalidate)
parent = c(
  '{',
  '  "type":"object",',
  '  "required":["child1"],',
  '  "properties":{',
  '    "child1":{',
  '      "$ref":"sub/child1.json"',
  '    }',
  '  }',
  '}'
)
child1 = c(
  '{',
  '  "type":"object",',
  '  "properties":{',
  '    "child2":{',
  '      "$ref":"child2.json"',
  '    }',
  '  }',
  '}'
)
child2 = c(
  '{',
  '  "type":"string",',
  '  "enum":["test"]',
  '}'
)

dir = file.path(tempdir(), "jsonvalidate_test")
schemadir = file.path(dir, "schemas")
schemasubdir1 = file.path(schemadir, "sub")
schemasubdir2 = file.path(schemasubdir1)
dir.create(schemasubdir2, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)  
writeLines(parent, file.path(schemadir, "parent.json"))  
writeLines(child1, file.path(schemasubdir1, "child1.json"))  
writeLines(child2, file.path(schemasubdir2, "child2.json"))  
list.files(schemadir, recursive = TRUE)
#> [1] "parent.json"     "sub/child1.json" "sub/child2.json"

json_validate('{"child1":{"child2":"test"}}', file.path(schemadir, "parent.json"), engine = "ajv")
#> [1] TRUE
json_validate('{"child1":{"child2":""}}', file.path(schemadir, "parent.json"), engine = "ajv")
#> [1] FALSE


unlink(dir, recursive = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it provides a proxy to ajv. It was hard to find if it provides the required interfaces, but I took a look at the tests.

It doesn't appear to expose the ajv function to manually add schemas, which is what I would tend to suggest.

https://github.com/ropensci/jsonvalidate/blob/33f286abc099d7de04fe98d768b7706b441af706/tests/testthat/test-validator.R#L261-L287

```
test_that("Referenced schemas have their ids replaced", {
  parent <- c(
    '{',
    '    "type": "object",',
    '    "properties": {',
    '        "hello": {',
    '            "$ref": "child.json"',
    '        }',
    '    },',
    '    "required": ["hello"],',
    '    "additionalProperties": false',
    '}')
  child <- c(
    '{',
    '    "id": "child",',
    '    "type": "string"',
    '}')
  path <- tempfile()
  dir.create(path)
  writeLines(parent, file.path(path, "parent.json"))
  writeLines(child, file.path(path, "child.json"))

  expect_silent(
    v <- json_validator(file.path(path, "parent.json"), engine = "ajv"))
  expect_false(v("{}"))
  expect_true(v('{"hello": "world"}'))
})
```

The key part is towards the end of the test. It looks like it may work if you have the schemas in a specific folder.

Further...

While the URIs used as references may contain a "path" section, they do not related to files or folders in your file system. AJV, the implementation that the tool you're using is a wrapper for, explicitly says that the location of files in the file system is not used. I can't tell you why you're able to reference the schema file in the same folder. It may be the wrapper library auto loads all in the same folder.

In the tests (which I linked to) for the r library, it specifically tests that "simple" file references work. It may well be they allowed for same folder references, but haven't allowed for referencing schemas in other folders. As such, you have to manually load in or dynamically resolve those references which should point to other folders. If you were using AJV directly, you could manually add the schemas you need. There are no docs that suggest the libaray you are using supports what you need. Sorry.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am not sure I understand what you are saying. As I pointed out in the question, the validation works if parent and children are in the same folder (which seems to be the case of the test). When the children are in a sub-folder of the parent folder, {jsonvalidate} can't resolve the path to the children.

Comment: While the URIs used as references may contain a "path" section, they do not related to files or folders in your file system. AJV, the implementation that the tool you're using is a wrapper for, explicitly says that the location of files in the file system is not used. I can't tell you why you're able to reference the schema file in the same folder. It may be the wrapper library auto loads all in the same folder. You would need to ask.

Comment: In the tests (which I linked to) for the r library, it specifically tests that "simple" file references work. It may well be they allowed for same folder references, but haven't allowed for referencing schemas in other folders. As such, you have to manually load in or dynamically resolve those references which should point to other folders. If you were using AJV directly, you could manually add the schemas you need. There are no docs that suggest the libaray you are using supports what you need. Sorry.

Comment: Can you add your comments to the answer, I think it would make it much better. I can't edit the answer because the queue is full. This part of the comments: "While the URIs used as references may contain a "path" section, they do not related to files or folders in your file system. AJV, the implementation that the tool you're using is a wrapper for, explicitly says that the location of files in the file system is not used. It may be the wrapper library auto loads all in the same folder. You would need to ask.

There are no docs that suggest the library you are using supports what you need."